# Retrieve record array from Delphi DLL with C#

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke, delphi-xe3

I'm trying to write a DLL in Delphi to allow my C# app to access an Advantage database (using VS2013 and not been able to access the data directly).

My issue is after I make the call, the array in C# is full of null values.

The Delphi DLL code:

```
TItem = record
  Id          : Int32;
  Description : PWideChar;
end;

function GetNumElements(const ATableName: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall;
var recordCount : Integer;
begin
... // code to get the number of records from ATableName
  Result := recordCount;
end;

procedure GetTableData(const ATableName: PWideChar; const AIdField: PWideChar; 
                       const ADataField: PWideChar; result: array of TItem); stdcall;
begin
  ... // ATableName, AIdField, and ADataField are used to query the specific table, then I loop through the records and add each one to result array
  index := -1;
  while not Query.Eof do begin
    Inc(index);
    result[index].Id := Query.FieldByName(AIdField).AsInteger;
    result[index].Description := PWideChar(Query.FieldByName(ADataField).AsString);
    Query.Next;
  end;
  ... // cleanup stuff (freeing created objects, etc)
end;
```

This appears to be working. I've used ShowMessage to show what the information going in looks like and what it looks like after.

The C# Code:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Explicit)] // also tried LayoutKind.Sequential without FieldOffset
public struct TItem
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int32 Id;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr),FieldOffset(sizeof(Int32))]
    public string Description;
}

public static extern void GetTableData(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string tableName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string idField,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string dataField, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] TItem[] items, int high);

public void GetListItems()
{
    int numProjects = GetNumElements("Project");

    TItems[] projectItems = new TItem[numProjects];

    GetTableData("Project", "ProjectId", "ProjectName", projectItems, numProjects);
}
```

This code executes, no errors of any kind, but when I iterate through projectItems each one returns

```
Id = 0
Description = null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few issues that I can see. First of all, I would declare the struct like this:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct TItem
{
    public Int32 Id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Description;
}
```

You'll need to use `UnmanagedType.BStr` so that the string can be allocated on the unmanaged side, and deallocated on the managed side. The alternative would be to marshal as `LPWStr` but then you'd have to allocate with `CoTaskMemAlloc` on the unmanaged side.

The Delphi record becomes:

```
type
  TItem = record
    Id          : Int32;
    Description : WideString;
  end;
```

You can clearly see that your code is wrong by looking at this line:

```
result[index].Description := PWideChar(Query.FieldByName(ADataField).AsString);
```

Here you make `result[index].Description` point to memory that will be deallocated when the function returns.

---

Trying to use a Delphi open array is risky at best. I would not do that. If you insist on doing so you should at least heed the value passed for `high` and not write over the end of the array. What's more, you should pass the right value for high. That is `projectItems.Length-1`.

Now, you are using pass by value for the array so nothing you write in the Delphi code will find its way back to the C# code. What's more, the C# code has `[In]` marshalling by default and so even when you switch to pass by var, the marshaller won't marshal the items back in to `projectItems` on the managed side.

Personally I'd stop using an open array and be explicit:

```
function GetTableData(
    ATableName: PWideChar; 
    AIdField: PWideChar; 
    ADataField: PWideChar; 
    Items: PItem;
    ItemsLen: Integer
): Integer; stdcall;
```

Here `Items` points to the first item in the array and `ItemsLen` gives the length of the supplied array. The function return value should be the number of items copied to the array.

To implement this use either pointer arithmetic, or `($POINTERMATH ON}`. I prefer the latter option. I don't think I need to demonstrate that.

On the C# side you have:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetTableData(
    string tableName,
    string idField,
    string dataField, 
    [In,Out] TItem[] items, 
    int itemsLen
);
```

Call it like this:

```
int len = GetTableData("Project", "ProjectId", "ProjectName", projectItems, 
    projectItems.Length);
// here you can check that the expected number of items were copied
```

---

Having said all of the above, I do have a doubt as to whether or not the marshaller will marshal an array of non-blittable types. I have a feeling that it won't. In which case your main options are:

1. Switch to passing the string back as `IntPtr` in the record. Allocate with `CoTaskMemAlloc`. Destroy on the managed side with `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`.
2. Use an open query, get next record interface, close query which would lead to multiple calls to the native code, each one returning a single item.

Personally I would opt for the latter approach.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks so much. Using the pointer arithmetic was something I'd not used before (and hence not considered), but now it seems so obvious.

Comment: Will the marshaller marshal that non-blittable array in both directions?

Comment: OK, thanks for that. Even after all these p/invoke questions I still an unable to anticipate whether or not the marshaller will gag on a particular complex type!